# How to work with a generic dictionary in a generic dictionary?

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have the following decleration:

```
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, File>> listFiles = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,File>>();
```

How do i add an item to the dictionary? Is there a better way to do something like this?
Info: That stores a sourcefilename, destinationfilename, and the file itself.

Edit1: Just figured it out, all I want to store is 3 values, where the second object of the outer dictionary stores a dictionary object, which isn't really the best way to do it, seeing that it will always contain just one KeyValuePair.

Edit2: With File i meant the binary data.

Edit3: I have a unsorted file list, which i need to sort, and then send somewhere else.

Comment: Storing a "file" in a collection is very murky.  A file is something that resides on a disk, not in memory.  Clarify what you really want to store.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data? Do a look up on source and/or destination or just source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, File>>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: this is not the same as dictionary of dictionaries, you woun't be able to have multiple secondary keys: it will be 1:1 correspondence as opposed to 1:N.

Comment: I think he wants same behaviour!!

Answer (score 2):

You can write a wrapper class `Dictionary<TKey1, TKey2, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey1, Dictionary<TKey2, TValue>>`

Answer (score 0):

To add a new File you'd do something like:

```
listFiles[srcFile] = new Dictionary<string, File>();
listFiles[srcFile][destFile] = file;
```

Note this will overwrite any mapping from an existing source file. However it seems what you really want is a map from (source) -> (dest, File), so in this case I'd make a class to contain the destination filename and the file and then create a dictionary to contain this lookup:

```
public class DestinationFileInfo { ... }
```

and then create a `Dictionary<string, DestinationFileInfo>`

Answer (score 0):

I did this once in a class I called DoubleKeyDictionary. I needed the functionality of a dictionary object, but I had 2 keys. If you have the data locked down really tight, you might try just appending it, e.g. take the string from key #1, add a ~ or some delimiter, and then add string #2, like blue~large, which would give you unique keys. Again, this works better with strings, and requires you lock the data down so a ~ in your string doesn't fubar the whole thing.

So what I did was initially what you did: Dictionary>, but the syntax was a little clumsy. So although it doesn't answer your question explicitly, here's my solution:

Create a class called MultiKeyDictionary, it contains a DataTable internally, and has a method for retrieving your Customer object or whatever. That method takes a params object[], and uses the DataTable.Select method to get the object. That way you can have as many keys as you like. You'll need methods for adding objects of course.

Answer (score 0):

When you find yourself nesting one generic inside another, consider creating a class. For example:

```
// todo: give this a name that better describes its purpose
public class FileContainer
{
    string DestinationFileName { get; set; }
    File File { get; set; }
}
```

Now, instead of this:

```
Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, File>>
```

you can work with this:

```
Dictionary<string, FileContainer>
```